# Python: Insert a string after each element of an array with an exception

Tags: python

I have the following Python script. What I want to do is add several strings to random.shuffle(scenArray). Specifically, there will be a string after each element of the array, however, the 8th element in the array will need a different string.

E.g. if the array is
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` I want to make it `1,A,2,A,3,A,4,A,5,A,6,A,7,A,8,B,9,A`

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import random

    # General comment: some of the script might be confusing because python
    # uses zero-based numbering to index arrays

    # read in the full list of scenario x conditions
    f = open('scenarioList.xml', 'U')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    inst = data.split("\n\n")

    # This specifies which scenarios are in which counterbalancing group
    cGroups = [[0,1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8,9],
    [10,11,12,13,14]]

    conds = [inst[0:15],inst[15:30],inst[30:45]] # the xml strings divided up by condition

    # this is the counterbalancing scheme (latin square)
    cScheme = [[1,2,3],
    [1,3,2],
    [2 ,1 , 3],
    [2 ,  3 ,  1],
    [3 ,  1  , 2],
    [3,   2 ,  1]]

    # change the second index in the range to loop up to 60; set to 12 now for testing
    for subj in range(1,12): 

        cRow = cScheme[(subj-1)%6] # use the modulus operator to find out which row to use in counterbalancing table

        scenArray = []

        # loop across scenario groups and look up their assigned interruption condition for this subj
        for group in range(0,3):
            #conds[cScheme[group]][i]

            scenArray.extend([ conds[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in cGroups[group]]) # use extend and not append here

        # randomize order of arrays---this is something you might modify to control this a bit more
        random.shuffle(scenArray)

        f = open('scenarios' + str(subj) + 'xml', 'w')
        f.write('\r\n\r\n'.join(scenArray))
        f.close()
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want these elements added *after* shuffling, right?  Because if you wanted them added before the list was shuffled, you could just as easily append them to the end of the list.

Comment: Wha you want to be shuffled in `1,A,2,A,3,A,4,A,5,A,6,A,7,A,8,B,9,A` ?

Comment: Yes I want them to be added after shuffling :)

Comment: I gave number line as an example - obviously I would not expect this in the real script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring all your code, but from your description and example:

> E.g. if the array is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
>
> I want to make it `1,A,2,A,3,A,4,A,5,A,6,A,7,A,8,B,9,A`

You could do something like:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

lst2 = sum(([x,'A'] if i != 7 else [x,'B'] for (i,x) in enumerate(lst1)), [])

print lst2  # [1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4, 'A', 5, 'A', 6, 'A', 7, 'A', 8, 'B', 9, 'A']
```

**EDIT**

The one-liner that is assigned to `lst2` can be equivalently re-written as:

```
lst3 = []  # Initialize an empty list
for (i,x) in enumerate(lst1):
    if i != 7:
        lst3 += [x,'A']  # This is just concatenates the list [x,'A'] with lst3
    else:
        lst3 += [x,'B']

print lst3  # [1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4, 'A', 5, 'A', 6, 'A', 7, 'A', 8, 'B', 9, 'A']
```

Note that `lst3 += [x, 'A']` could also be written as

```
lst3.append(x)
lst3.append('A')
```

Also, `sum()` is used with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and it's optional *start* argument.

Finally, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a generator-like object that, when iterated over, produces a `(index, value)` tuple at each iteration -- see the docs I linked for a small example.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help. No worries if you are busy, but would you by any chance be able to explain (or provide a link) which could explain to me why this does the job it does :)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I edited in some explanation of what the one-liner is all about.  Let me know if I can help clarify.

Comment: Again, I cannot thank you enough :) - When/if I have any additional questions I will let you know.